# Does passing an object by value create two instances of a file system watcher?

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes. One class is my "Worker" class which has a file system watcher. The main form (class A) holds a reference to each instantiated Worker object in a List (_workerList). If I pass _workerList to class B (which I did via constructor) and save a copy of that list in class B, does that mean I have two instances of the file system watcher running at the same time?

```
public partial class A : Form
{
    private List<Worker> _workerList;

    public A()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _workerList = new List<Worker>();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _workerList.Add(new Worker());  //the worker class contains a file system watcher

        using( B b = new B(_workerList))
        {
            b.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

public partial class B : Form
{ 
    private List<Worker> _workerListCopy;

    public B(List<Worker> originalWorkerList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _workerListCopy = new List<Worker>(originalWorkerList)
    }

}
```

Comment: There are two different instances of list because of `_workerListCopy = new List<Worker>(originalWorkerList);`, but both list points to same `Worker` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

But maybe not for the reasons you think. You created a `class` called "Worker". This means its automatically a reference type. Reference types are passed by value, but as a *reference* (a copy is not made).

You can change the object itself, but changes to the what the reference points at will not be reflected the original variable.

This means that because you didn't use the `new` operator again to create a new `Worker` class, only one `FileSystemWatcher` is created.

Comment: That's a little bit misleading.  Reference types are almost always passed by value, but it's the *reference* being passed by value, not the object itself... (not my downvote, but still, though I'd mention)

Comment: @ReedCopsey Well, by that logic everything is passed by value, even if you are passing a reference (or a reference to a reference). I'll try and think of a way to make it clearer though.

Comment: Not really -  It's very clear and explicit.  Had it been a reference type passed by ref, it's passed by reference.  If you don't have `ref` or `out`, you're always passing by value.  Otherwise, assigning to the parameter would impact the outer scope... There is no "reference to reference" in C#, and the spec is very clear on this.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I see what you are getting at, hopefully you will find my new revision more clear/accurate.

Comment: Great. I was hoping this would be the case. Thank you for your speedy answers. Learned something new as well. So to be clear, passing an object to another class is automatically being passed by reference, while if I passed an int variable (without the ref or out keywords) it would be passed by value, meaning the class I passed the variable to gets a copy of that variable?

Comment: @AceK47 Thats correct. Objects are always passed "by reference" as clarified in my post. The actual reference is of course, passed by value.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yeah - looks better.  I still wouldn't say "Reference types are never passed by value" even qualified, but at least now your intent/meaning is much more clear.

Comment: @AceK47 No, that is not correct.  The parameter is passed by value, as every single parameter always is without `ref` or `out`.  *The value of the parameter is itself a reference*.  Passing the value to another method is merely copying that reference, not the object that the reference points to.  That is radically different from passing the object *by* reference, and understanding this semantic difference is essential to understanding the behavior of objects in C#.

Comment: @Servy I really think there is some confusion here stemming from definition of terms (which everyone is doing a good job of clarifying). Coming from C++, I think of objects as being passed be reference because I don't get the object itself, I get a reference to it. If I want to change the reference, I have to pass by ref (similar to a ** argument). If C# had pointers, it would be more accurate to say we pass objects by pointer, but it doesn't, so we have to use the less precise term "reference" instead. Hopefully that clears up at least what I am trying to say.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET If you come from C++ then you should know exactly what it means to pass something by reference, versus passing a reference by value.  Passing a value by reference is to use the `&` operator.  Passing a reference by value is to pass a pointer to a value.  Passing a reference by reference is to pass a pointer using the `&` operator.  Here he is passing a reference by value, not a value by reference, *and the two have different semantics*.  One cannot conflate the two as you have incorrectly done.

Comment: @Servy I agree (hence saying it would be better to say we are passing by pointer) perhaps I should just put it as you have, that you are passing a reference by value, as opposed to simply passing by reference. That would seem to be a much clearer way of saying it. Just to be clear, I agree completely that they have different semantics

Answer (score 2):

You're creating two instances of `List<Worker>`, but they're sharing the same `Worker` references.

This won't create two sets of `FileSystemWatcher` instances.

Answer (score 2):

In class `A` you've created a `List<Worker>`:

```
_workerList -> []  // empty list
```

Then you add some `Worker`s to it:

```
_workerList -> [ worker1, worker2 ]
```

Now the thing here is that the list `_workerList` doesn't contain the objects `worker1` and `worker2`, it contains *references* to those objects:

```
                 worker1   worker2

_workerList ->  [   ↑     ,   ↑     ]
```

When you create a new list in class `B` like this:

```
_workerListCopy = new List<Worker>(originalWorkerList);
```

What you are going to do is make a *shallow* copy of the original list. It will copy the *references* not the objects that those references point to. So you end up with something like this:

```
_workerCopy ->  [   ↓         ↓     ]

                 worker1   worker2

_workerList ->  [   ↑     ,   ↑     ]
```

So although you have two lists with 2 `Worker` objects in each of them, they are the *same* two `Worker` objects in both lists. You only have a total of 2 `Worker` objects and one set of `FileSystemWatcher` (one for each unique instance of `Worker`).

You can confirm this pretty easily by doing something like this:

```
bool areTheSame = _workList[0] == _workerCopy[0];   // should be true
```

Since `Worker` are reference types, the default equality is to compare whether they are point to the same object.

Note, however, you do now have two separate lists that just happen to have references to the same objects. If you change one list by adding or removing a `Worker`, the original list will be unaffected because the list are independent of each other.

Comment: So lets say there are 2 references to Worker in my list. If, in class B I remove the reference of one of the Workers from the _workerListCopy list, would this change also remove the same reference from the list in class A (_workerList)?

Comment: @AceK47: No - it would not. The list are independent. They just happen to point to the same objects. But removing an object from one list will not remove it from the other.